# Site navigation

Tags: php, html, css

I am making a website in HTML, CSS and PHP. I have a navigation on the top of the page, and when you hover your mouse over the buttons, they light up.

Now, when you click a button and go to that particular page, I would like the button for that page to be lit up, indicating that you are on that page. How would I go about doing this? Defining a variable on each page and then checking for it in the menu is not possible, as I have a forum on the site too, and that would require me to define a variable on each page.

**EDIT**

I managed to solve my problem. As it turns out, I could just define the pages, and for the forum I could do the same in the settings file that the forum used.

In my navigation, I just check what the current page is:

```
<li id="news"><a <? if(PAGE == "INDEX") print 'class="active"'; ?> href="/">News</a></li>
```

Comment: How about passing parameters?

Comment: what's your url(query-string) when you navigate to another page?

Comment: How should the page know which button to lighten up? The usual way is to add a class attribute to the current page, but you specifically ruled out such solutions. What other unique attributes do you have that can guide the code to what button to lighten up?

Comment: make clear pages are php or html ?

Comment: The pages are PHP, I should have made that clearer I think.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class (or ID) to the `body` tag, like so:

`<body class="Page1">...</body>`

Then, in your CSS you can say something like:

```
.Page1 menu li, menu li:hover {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to check for the current page in PHP - though, that would be ideal.

If you want to rely on JavaScript, though, I have used this function in the past successfully:

```
function highlightPage(id){
    //make sure DOM methods are understood
    if(!document.getElementsByTagName) return false;
    if(!document.getElementById) return false;
    if(!document.getElementById(id)) return false;
    var nav = document.getElementById(id);
    var links = nav.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i=0; i < links.length; i++){
        var linkurl = links[i].getAttribute('href');
        var currenturl = window.location.href;
        //indexOf will return -1 on non-matches, so we're checking for a positive match
        if (currenturl.indexOf(linkurl) != -1) {
            links[i].className = "here";
            var linktext = links[i].lastChild.nodeValue.toLowerCase();
            document.body.setAttribute("id",linktext);
        }
    }
}
```

And to load the function at the load of the page:

```
function addLoadEvent(func){
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
        window.onload = function(){
            oldonload();
            func();
        }
    }
}

addLoadEvent(function(){
    highlightPage('navigation');
    });
```

This assumes that your navigation has the ID of "navigation", but you can change it to whatever you want. The function simply attaches a class of "here" to the current navigation item.

This script comes [from Jeremy Keith's "DOM Scripting"](http://domscripting.com/).